Change LogLevel at runtime for standard ILogger in ASP.NET
currently I'm configuring my API service to use minimum LogLevel like this:
[other code...]

builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);

[other code...]

and also by specifying LogLevel from appsettings.json
I would like to change the LogLevel without restarting the application, maybe by using a dedicated endpoint like api/log/changelevel/trace for example.
Is it possible to do that with built-in logger without using 3rd party loggers like log4net, serilog, nlog .... ?
Thank you

From the MS documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#change-log-levels-in-a-running-app  -- "The Logging API doesn't include a scenario to change log levels while an app is running. However, some configuration providers are capable of reloading configuration, which takes immediate effect on logging configuration. ..."  There is also this:  https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/15698

If you doesn't mind using custom logger provider that will be achievable. But I would rather use 3rd party package in this scenario.

I've used log4net in the past. Is it still a viable solution? I've read somewhere that there were some vulnerability issues with that library.
